# What is the best way to store node.js site settings?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to ask about best way of storing Node.JS config in project.

I tried store it in file like settings.json. But I always need to restart the server, or, in each place use

```
var settings = require('../settings.json');
```

Because I can update this file through admin panel and I want immediate changes.

If I use MongoDB, I must always call:

```
var settings = Settings.findOne({});
```

But can I store config, which I can edit and it will immediately change in all files?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: @NishantGhodke Hmmmm... Stange question. I'm using Node.js + Express.js

Comment: Configuration data is very limited, and used only at a handful of places in the project. I would recommend to follow the good -old-way of `require` ing the config file. My previous question was to know if you're using framework like loopback, sails.js where these issues are taken care of in the app object.

Comment: @NishantGhodke, oh, so sorry. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share the file across components and you don't want to require everywhere, you can place it in the `global` namespace in node. i.e:

```
global.config = require('./yourFile.json');
```

`global` is accessible from all your scripts so you don't need to require the config everywhere and if you overwrite values in the file you can create a service that writes to the file using [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) (to persist your changes) and updates the config in the `global` namespace.